# Idempotence, trace = rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a projection $P$, i.e. $P = P^2$, show that 
$\mathrm{rank}\,P = \mathrm{tr}\,P$. Does there exist a similar formula if we instead have $P^3 = P$?

I have shown the first part, by showing that there only exists eigenvalues $\lambda = 0,1$, and that the eigenspace of 1 is the image of $P$, and then it is somewhat trivial. However, when $P^3 = P$, we find $\lambda = 0,1,-1$, and by this I cannot find a similar relation between eigenspaces and the image. How can one proceed, if the answer is presumed to be positive?

Comment: Clearly all you can expect to recover from the trace is the difference of dimensions between the eigenspaces for $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P=P^3$, then 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(P)= \operatorname{trace}(P^2)
$$
I will leave the proof to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I will be able to finish the proof!

Comment: Before I get with it, just out of curiosity, is it possible to continue finding "similar" formulas if $P^n = P$, for some integer $n$?

Comment: Sure.  Note that
$$
x^n - x = (x^{n-1} - 1)x
$$
so, every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P$ would have to satisfy $\lambda^{n-1} = 1$ or $\lambda = 0$ and, importantly, $P$ is necessarily diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ (in particular, $P$ has no generalized eigenvectors associated with $0$).  So, we would have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(P) = \operatorname{trace}(P^{n-1})
$$